# If deterministic wavelet is better for well ties , why do people use statistical wavelet too for wellties?

Tags: seismology, seismic

Synthetic trace generated with deterministic wavelet gives a higher correlation with real seismics.

Though it's more accurate for seismic well ties than statistical wavelet, but there is always an option for creating synthetic trace with statisctical wavelet ?

My question is : Why to use statistical wavelet, if deterministic is more accurate for well tying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, even if the well logs were available for a deterministic approach, the logs are not aligned with seismic. To get the initial alignment one could use synthetic trace which is done by extracting the  *statistical wavelet* and convolving it with impedance values. Then after the alignment the deterministic approach could be used.